# Python requests - TypeError: put() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.myurl.com'
data = {
               'amount':'10',
               'currency':'USD',
               'notificationUrl':'http://www.url.com/response',
               'memo':'Just a test',
               'paymentAckMessage':'Thank you'
              }

result = requests.put(url, data, 'auth=uniquekey', verify=False)
print result
print result.text
```

I cant seem to figure out what to do about the following error: TypeError: put() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

I need all 4 arguments based on the requirement from the REST service I am calling, but how do I manage to go around the error Python is giving me?

Comment: If I do that this error pops out: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: You need four arguments in the request, not four arguments to `put`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean `auth='uniqekey'`, but that's not the only problem.

See the implementation of `auth` inside the `models.py` module:

```
if auth:
    if isinstance(auth, tuple) and len(auth) == 2:
        # special-case basic HTTP auth
        auth = HTTPBasicAuth(*auth)

    # Allow auth to make its changes.
    r = auth(self)
```

`auth` should be a *tuple*.

Comment: So I tried that, but then the error I get is this: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I do agree with you, but since I have another error that is harder to solve, it would be great to know how I get around passing 4 parameters, rather than just 2 in the put call.

Comment: @Marc `put` sends a PUT request, it's defined as `put(url, data=None, **kwargs)`, AFAIK, `auth` is meant to be a *tuple* of (un, pw).

Comment: Requests doc : "auth – (optional) Auth tuple to enable Basic/Digest/Custom HTTP Auth.".

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what to do from here on. What do I need to do about the error I was given?